# AngularJS: UI Router doesn't load the inline template and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

This is my first time using [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) inside AngularJS project. I have a problem where when I click a link to view a post, it doesn't show up.

The post template is not showing and I'm still at the home page. I can see the URL flashing like `http://localhost:8000/#/posts/1` and attempt to change, but, it goes back to `http://localhost:8000/#/home`.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KV6lwzKUHrIZgVWVdrzt

What I am missing here?

Note 1: I already read [UI Router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) and I think I'm not missing anything.

Note 2: I'm following [this tutorial](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails) (thinkster).

Note 3: I'm using SimpleHTTPServer `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` command to serve this project.

This is my **app.js**:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .state('posts', {
            url: 'posts/:id',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

}]);

...

app.controller("PostsCtrl", ["$scope", "$stateParams", "postsFactory", function($scope, $stateParams, postsFactory){

    // grab the right post from postsFactory posts array
    $scope.post = postsFactory.posts[$stateParams.id];
    console.log($scope.post);
}]);
```

And this is my **index.html**:

```
<ui-view></ui-view> 

...

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Note that you are linking to `#posts/:id`, while the router is set-up to respond to /posts/:id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue in your code is in your router config for `posts` state. It should be like below. URL should be `/posts/:id` instead of `posts/:id`.

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('posts', {
            url: '/posts/:id',
            templateUrl: '/posts.html',
            controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are basically missing `/` slash at the start of your `posts` state URL, because of `/` is missing it was redirecting to `.otherwise` rule of `$urlRouterProvider`

**Code**

```
.state('posts', {
    url: '/posts/:id',
    templateUrl: '/posts.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in the `app.config` block and `<'base href="/"'>` in the head section of your HTML file.

Otherwise, the `#/posts/:id` routing won't work.